# Passing parameter through @lang method in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, localization, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

Translating some cities in the local array need to make some problem on Laravel 5.4. I try the following way but it is failed.

$popular_cities = ['log_angel','new_york','colombo'];

```
@foreach ($popular_cities as $city)
                    <li><a href="">@lang('ui.{{$city}}')</a></li>
                @endforeach
```

but it is failed to show the name as mentioned in my language file

### ui.php in lang directory

```
<?php
     return [
     'log_angel' => 'Los Angel',
     'new_york' => 'New York', 
     'colombo' => 'Colombo'
];
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are in Blade function, only use :

```
<li><a href="">@lang('ui.'. $city)</a></li>
```